# How to search for specific string within a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of Id's in one column.  sometimes the cell has a single id, sometimes a cell has multiple id's:

```
[ "52b46bfc763f4ad9198b45ab", "533c0cba763f4a505e8b46db" ] - multiple id's
52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6 - single id
```

I'm using `COUNTIF` to count all the instances of a given id.  if there were only a single id in each cell, it would work.  But, when there are more than one id in a cell it fails.

How do I count the number of times a given instance shows up in the column?  Happy to use excel functions or VBA.

thanks

Comment: Do multiple ID's have square brackets around them on the actual spreadhseet?

Answer (score 4):

use **wildcards:**

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6*")
```

for example:

[image: COUNTIF]

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Minor point: on testing this I found it did not pick up case where multiple IDs are same e.g. `52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6, 52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6`?

Comment: @AlexP I doubt that would be an issue.  If one needed to take into account multiple instances of the same ID in a given cell, I would use something like:  =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6","")))/LEN("52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6"))

Comment: i think this is working: `=COUNTIF(vendorOutput.csv!$F$2:$F$1782, "*"&O241&"*")`.  Is that how you'd do it?

Answer (score 1):

I like `Gary's Student` approach for ease.

For reference here is a VBA solution using a user-defined function. Example:

```
    A                                                       B
1   52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6                                `=COUNTIDS(A1)` = 4
2   52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6, 52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6
3   52c2ff91763f4a572d8b45e6
4   52b46bfc763f4ad9198b45ab, 533c0cba763f4a505e8b46db
```

This code inside a VBA module:

```
Function CountIDs(id As Range)
    Dim ids As Range, cl As Range, cnt As Long, arr As Variant, i As Integer

    Set ids = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row) //amend to suit your set-up
    cnt = 0

    For Each cl In ids
        If InStr(1, cl, ",", vbTextCompare) Then
            arr = Split(cl, ",")

            For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                If VBA.Trim(arr(i)) = id Then
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                End If
            Next i

        Else
            If cl = id Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    CountIDs = cnt
End Function
```